# Buffer for String like IntBuffer

Tags: java, string, buffer

Is there a class in Java ( 8+ ) that has similar functionalities as `IntBuffer` or other classes inheriting fom `java.nio.Buffer` but for `String` items? Implementing my own version would be simple for my need is very simple (only mark a position in the middle of the array), but I'd like to know if there is already a class for that.

Thanks.

**Update**: I'm sorry if the problem wasn't understood clearly, but what I need is to mark a position in the array of strings, i. e. to save the last used index so I know when all the array has been used. Like:

```
String[] array = new String(){"str1", "str2", ...};
int mark = 0;
String get() throws Exception{
   // Throw exception if out of bound
   return array[mark++];
}
boolean hasNext(){
   return mark<array.length();
}
```

which is what `IntBuffer` does with `int` items, I think.

Thanks.

Comment: `String`s don't have a fixed size, so a buffer wouldn't know where one string "starts" and where another "ends". Are you looking for `CharBuffer` perhaps? Or maybe this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: The behavior you want from `get()` and `hasNext()` is very similar to an `Iterator`. So, you could just have a `List<String>`, even a fixed-size one wrapping a `String[]` via `Collections#asList(T[])`, and then get an `Iterator<String>` from it (or a `ListIterator<String>` if you want to go backwards as well as forwards). Or you could easily create your own class wrapping a `String[]` that does what you want (though I don't believe it would make sense for it to extend `java.nio.Buffer`). That said, if you want a buffer of _characters_ use `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, or `CharBuffer`.

Comment: @Slaw you probably mean `java.util.Arrays#asList(T[])` (there is no `Collections#asList()`)

Comment: @ThomasKläger Oops. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Slaw pointed out, [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) does what you want:

```
String[] array = {"str1", "str2", "str3"};
Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList(array).iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String element = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

If you want to keep track of the current index in the list/array, or if you want to be able to navigate both forwards and backwards, you can use a [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html):

```
String[] array = {"str1", "str2", "str3"};
Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList(array).listIterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String element = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

(This code is identical to the first code block, except for calling `listIterator()` instead of `iterator()`.)

The Iterator, ListIterator, and Arrays classes are all in the java.util package.

Answer (score 0):

Java has `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` which might be what you're looking for. A string object in Java is immutable which means that each time you modify it, it generates a new string and this puts a lot of strain on the garbage collector. For concatenation or string operations in a multithreaded environment, use `StringBuilder`. Otherwise, `StringBuffer` should work just fine.

Read more here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder